# Basic AngularJS: Send JSON with $http

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http, cordova

So I'm still getting my bearings straight with AngularJS and can't seem to get over this wall... I'm trying to send a JSON object over http to my server/service at the end of my iPhone application (using Cordova/PhoneGap). I basically need this JSON object.

```
{
   "Subject" : {
       "BiographicData" : [
           {
               "Key" : "BarcodeID",
               "Value" : "567891234"
           },
           {
               "Key" : "Gender",
               "Value" : "Male"
           },
           {
               "Key" : "BirthDate",
               "Value" : "8/20/1964"
           },
           {
               "Key" : "Name",
               "Value" : "Success"
           }
       ]
   },
   "GroupID" : "84",
   "ClientID" : "8"
}
```

So that's a JSON with three members--GroupId, ClientID, and Subject, where Subject contains an array of Key/Value pairs called BiographicData. Here I try to create this object in AngularJS and send it with `$http` on the click of `$scope.finishBtn`:

```
app.controller('finishController', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, $http) {
  $scope.success = ($routeParams.success == 'true') ? true : false;
  $scope.transactionid = barcode.id;

  POSTOBJ = new Object();
  POSTOBJ.GroupID = "28";
  POSTOBJ.ClientID = "1";

  BiographicData0 = new Object();
  BiographicData0.Value = "567891234";
  BiographicData0.Key = "BarcodeID";

  BiographicData1 = new Object();
  BiographicData1.Value = "Testing";
  BiographicData1.Key = "Customer_FirstName";

  BiographicData2 = new Object();
  BiographicData2.Value = "Female";
  BiographicData2.Key = "Gender";

  BiographicData3 = new Object();
  BiographicData3.Value = "8/20/1964";
  BiographicData3.Key = "BirthDate";

  POSTOBJ.Subject.BiographicData = new Array(BiographicData0,BiographicData1,BiographicData2,BiographicData3);

  //BiometricDatas0 = new Object();
  //BiometricDatas0.Type = "Image";
  //BiometricDatas0.Modality = "TEST";
  //BiometricDatas0.Base64Data = "AAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQN";

  //POSTOBJ.Subject.BiometricDatas = new Array(BiometricDatas0);

  $scope.finishBtn = function(){
    $http({
      url: 'http://serverIPAddress/RestProxy/api/myService',
      method: "ENROLL",
      data: POSTOBJ,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/JS'}
    });
  }
});
```

Final note: I know the method is not GET/POST/ect... My service is built to accept the custom ENROLL verb, and I have verified that everything works server-side with a test client. I just need to fix the output from my iPhone application so that it works like my test client. Can anyone let me know if I'm heading in the right direction, and if not perhaps point me towards it. Much appreciated!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you creating your object in such an unnecessary way? Why not just copy and post the json object and set var POSTOBJ = {subject:... blah}. It is JavaScript Object Notation for a reason.

Comment: At first I just thought that this way was cleaner or easier to read... but you're right. I've changed it as you've said :)

Comment: Did that help with the post? Your method: might need to be 'post' also, rather than 'enroll'.

Comment: That's kinda one of my main concerns... do you (or anybody else) know of problems with angularjs $http and custom verbs?

Comment: What does the chrome network tab shows as sent? (F12->network -> refresh-> click request). From the small bit of angular code I've looked for, non compliant methods should be supported ( search for the  createXhr() function in the angular.js code)

Comment: Problem solved: just had to change the headers parameter from {'Content-Type': 'application/JS'} to {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

The devil is in the details!!